# Disabling UIAlertAction but don't want the the title to be grey/dimmed

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I have a UIAlertController in the form of an actionsheet, I manage to add a UISwitch button on to one of my UIAlertAction, but the thing is that if the user doesn't touch perfectly on the UISwitch button, he touch the UIAction and my actionsheet disappears. So I decided to disable the UIAlertAction to prevent this behavior.

```
myAction.isEnabled = false
```

Now, it's working but the text/title of my UIAlertAction gets grey/dimmed which is normal, but I would like this not to happen. I would eventually like to apply my own color to it. I tried to set it after I disabled it with :

```
myAction.setValue(myColor, forKey: "titleTextColor")
```

but the text stays grey. Does someone know how to prevent this behavior ? Or if someone has an other solution for my problem I would be happy to hear it.

Here's a screenshot of my problem so you probably will understand better:

[image: screenshot of my actionsheet]

Comment: Do you really have to use UIAlertController to show an alert message?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean ?

Comment: What @ElTomato means is: What you seem to be looking for is not "really" a UIAlertController. An AlertController gives the user the choice between independent options – but your "Mode sombre" is not really an option since you can't select it as an independent choice. Maybe you need to show a different/self made View instead of the UIAlertController

Comment: Well, I understand what you mean but I wanted to implement it like that. For your information "mode sombre" means dark mode in french. And I wanted to to implement this feature from the actionsheet, is it a serious mistake ? I'm asking that because I'm kind of new.